# How do I check connectivity/reachability between two resources within a VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I have various resources, eg ECS ENIs, EC2 instances, Transit Gateways, etc.

For EC2 I usually SSH in and run curl but this doesn't work with resources like the containers in ECS which cannot be SSH'd into and may not have curl or another network utility installed.

My environment is also pretty locked down so sometimes I don't have permission to hop on a box or run an experimental ECS task.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 8):

There is a really nice feature called [VPC Reachability Analyzer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-insights-analyzes-reachability-and-visibility-in-vpcs/) which solves this problem.

You can go to `AWS Console => VPC => VPC Reachability Analyzer`.

You basically set a source and a destination, run the analyzer, and it tells you if the networking is set up properly to allow for connections. You can give it a port as well.

Right now it supports most networking resources including

- Transit Gateways
- VPN Gateways
- EC2 Instances
- Network Interfaces (ENI)
- Internet Gateways
- VPC Endpoints
- VPC Peering connections

There's also a CLI interface.